# Pandas: Calculate the percentage of multiple columns, saving the result in new columns - best way

Tags: python, pandas

My aim is to get the percentage of multiple columns, that are divided by another column. The resulting columns should be kept in the same dataframe.

```
        A    B  Divisor
2000    8   31  166
2001    39  64  108
2002    68  8   142
2003    28  2   130
2004    55  61  150
```

result:

```
        A   B   Divisor  perc_A   perc_B
2000    8   31  166      4.8      18.7
2001    39  64  108      36.1     59.3
2002    68  8   142      47.9     5.6
2003    28  2   130      21.5     1.5
2004    55  61  150      36.7     40.7
```

My solution:

```
def percentage(divisor,columns,heading,dframe):
    for col in columns:  
        heading_new = str(heading+col)
        dframe[heading_new] = (dframe.loc[:,col]/dframe.loc[:,divisor])*100   
    return dframe

df_new = division("Divisor",df.columns.values[:2],"perc_",df)
```

The solution above worked.But is there a more effective way to get the solution?

(I know there are already similar questions. But I couldn't find one, where I can save the results in the same dataframe without loosing the original columns)

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) for add new columns created by [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) by first 2 columns selected by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), multiple by `100` and [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df = df.join(df.iloc[:, :2].div(df['Divisor'], axis=0).mul(100).add_prefix('perc_'))
print (df)

       A   B  Divisor     perc_A     perc_B
2000   8  31      166   4.819277  18.674699
2001  39  64      108  36.111111  59.259259
2002  68   8      142  47.887324   5.633803
2003  28   2      130  21.538462   1.538462
2004  55  61      150  36.666667  40.666667
```

Your function should be changed:

```
def percentage(divisor,columns,heading,dframe):
    return df.join(df[columns].div(df[divisor], axis=0).mul(100).add_prefix(heading))

df_new = percentage("Divisor",df.columns.values[:2],"perc_",df)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can reshape the divisor:

```
df[['perc_A', 'perc_B']] = df[['A', 'B']] / df['Divisor'].values[:,None] * 100
```